# Python: Return Pandas DataFrame from FuzzyWuzzy ExtractOne()

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

I have two Pandas DataFrames (person names), one small (200+ rows) and another one pretty big (100k+ rows). They both have similar header but the big one has an unique ID too, as following:

```
Small: LST_NM, FRST_NM, CITY
Big: LST_NM, FRST_NM, CITY, UNIQUE_ID
```

Small: `df2 = pd.DataFrame([['Doe','John','New York'], ['Obama', 'Barack', 'New York']], columns = ['FRST_NM', 'LST_NM', 'CITY_NM'])`

> [image: Small]

Big:  `df = pd.DataFrame([['Doe','John','New York', 'N1'], ['Obama', 'Barack Hussein', 'New York', 'N2'], ['Obama', 'Michelle', 'Chicago', 'N3'], ['Trump', 'Donald', 'New York', 'N4']], columns = ['FRST_NM', 'LST_NM', 'CITY_NM', 'UNIQUE_ID'])`

> [image: Big]

I use the below code:

```
import itertools
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
import time
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp
from unidecode import unidecode
import re

#read the CSV files;
df = pd.read_csv("BIG.csv", encoding="utf-8")
df2 = pd.read_csv("SMALL.csv", encoding="utf-8")

#create function to clean the columns
def clean_column(column):
    column = unidecode(column)
    column = re.sub('\n', ' ', column)
    column = re.sub('-', ' ', column)
    column = re.sub('/', ' ', column)
    column = re.sub("'", '', column)
    column = re.sub(",", '', column)
    column = re.sub(":", ' ', column)
    column = re.sub('  +', ' ', column)
    column = column.strip().strip('"').strip("'").lower().strip()
    if not column :
        column = None
    return column

#Normalize, create FULL_NM by combining FRST_NM / LST_NM and then create MIN_CITY as the first three chars from CITY_NM:
df['FULL_NM'] = (df['LST_NM'] + ' ' + df['FRST_NM']).apply(lambda x: fuzz._process_and_sort(clean_column(x), True, True))
df['MIN_CITY'] = (df['CITY_NM']).astype(str).apply(lambda x: clean_column(x[:3]))

df2['FULL_NM'] = (df2['LST_NM'] + ' ' + df2['FRST_NM']).apply(lambda x: fuzz._process_and_sort(clean_column(x), True, True))
df2['MIN_CITY'] = (df2['CITY_NM']).astype(str).apply(lambda x: clean_column(x[:3]))

#create match1 function; it uses the FULL_NM as lookup field
def match1(x, choices, scorer, cutoff):
        match = process.extractOne(x['FULL_NM'], choices=choices.loc[choices['MIN_CITY'] == x['MIN_CITY'],'FULL_NM'], 
                                   scorer=scorer, 
                                   score_cutoff=cutoff)
        if match:
            return match[0]

#and finally... create the MATCH_NM column by applying match1 function as following:
df2['MATCH_NAME'] = df2.apply(match1, args=(df, fuzz.token_set_ratio, 80), axis=1)
```

I want to lookup info from the big one into the small one, bringing the UNIQUE_ID. To speed up the process, I created smaller chunks (using first three letters of City). This new column (created in both DataFrames) is named MIN_CITY.

The code above works well but it brings only the matched name (MATCH_NAME). I don't want to reverse (bring from Small into Big and then filter). How could I get the UNIQUE_ID from process.ExtractOne()? I need to mention that I am very new into Python / Pandas / FuzzyWuzzy.

Comment: Hi @c_c. Can you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Done! Sorry, I'm new on StackOverflow! Thanks for the tip, I'll keep this in mind for the future!

Comment: Sure. Please check the answer. Also giving an MVC as a code will be recommended instead of pics. Like: `df2 = pd.DataFrame([['Doe','John','New York'], ['Obama', 'Barack', 'New York']], columns = ['FRST_NM', 'LST_NM', 'CITY_NM'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look into [fuzzymatcher](https://github.com/RobinL/fuzzymatcher):

```
from fuzzymatcher import link_table, fuzzy_left_join

left_on = ['FULL_NM']
right_on = ['FULL_NM']

fuzzy_left_join(df2, df, left_on, right_on)
```

Gives a table:

```
best_match_score    __id_left   __id_right  FRST_NM_left    LST_NM_left CITY_NM_left    FULL_NM_left    MIN_CITY_left   MATCH_NAME  FRST_NM_right   LST_NM_right    CITY_NM_right   UNIQUE_ID   FULL_NM_right   MIN_CITY_right
0   0.167755    0_left  0_right Doe John    New York    doe john    new doe john    Doe John    New York    N1  doe john    new
1   0.081166    1_left  1_right Obama   Barack  New York    barack obama    new barack hussein obama    Obama   Barack Hussein  New York    N2  barack hussein obama    new
```

Here are some [examples](https://github.com/RobinL/fuzzymatcher/blob/master/examples.ipynb).

If you have to insist on using fuzzy_wuzzy.process.extractOne, you can match and find    the unique_id from the matched name like:

```
def match1(x, choices, scorer, cutoff):
        match = process.extractOne(x['FULL_NM'], choices=choices.loc[choices['MIN_CITY'] == x['MIN_CITY'],'FULL_NM'], 
                                   scorer=scorer, 
                                   score_cutoff=cutoff)
        if match:
            return choices[choices['FULL_NM'] == 'doe john'].UNIQUE_ID[0]
```

Comment: Thanks, Nihal! Works well. Do you know, maybe, where I can find additional info of this library? It lacks on documentation. For example, I want to change the scorer and ad a custom DataPreprocessor. I can't find examples...