# is there a method to filter in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe `df1`

```
Name ; id ; address
John Nicola,MD, doctor ; 45 ; 34,Street 78363 NEW YORK
Alfred Dubo,Prof ; 65 ; Street 76353,CANADA
```

and i have another dataframe `df2` :

```
firstname ; lastname ; city ; id
John ; Nicola ; NEW YORK
```

i want  to fill the `id` field of `df2` from `df1` according to some condition :

```
if (
  df2['fristname'] in df1['Name'] AND
  df2['lastname'] in df1['Name'] AND
  df2['city'] in df1['address']
):
```

Comment: You can use the `df1[df1['Name'].str.contains(df2['firstname'])]` to find all row of `df1` which in their `Name` exist `df2['firstname']`.

Comment: I'd suggest using `fuzzywuzzy` where you can, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55570851/1358308 points to a nice wrapper that knows about Pandas

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.